# A difficulty in understanding a paragraph in Hungerford Algebra introduction.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

Could anyone explain the last statement in this paragraph please:

> Let $\displaystyle\prod_{i \in I}A_{i}$ be a Cartesian product. For each $k \in I$ define a map $\displaystyle\pi_k : \prod_{i \in I}A_i \to A_k$ by $f \mapsto f(k)$, or in the other notation $\{a_i\} \mapsto a_k$. $\pi_{k}$ is called **(canonical) projection** of the product onto its $k$th component (or factor). If every $A_i$ is nonempty, then each $\pi_k$ is surjective (see Excercise 7.6).

Comment: I think your question/confusion might be: if one $A_i$ is empty, then the entire product is empty - in which case the projection onto a factor $A_k$ has a hard time being onto.

Comment: I think that there is also an issue with the scan---the little mark in the last sentence is not a comma; I think that the sentence should read "If every $A_i$ is nonempty...", not "If every $A$, is nonempty..."

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535240/a-difficulty-in-understanding-a-statement-in-hungerford-algebra).

Comment: yes this is exactly my question @peterag

Comment: @XanderHenderson  yes the little mark is not a comma it is an i